# Overlay Visual Studio Code extension view container icon to visualize some changes in extension functionality

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Can we show a number or some color coding on top of my extension view container icon from code like how visual studio code shows a number of files to be saved on file structure present on the 
top left, when we edit any files?

Comment: create an issue to export the API to construct a badge for the icon. The class of the numbers is `badge`. The SCM icon at the start shows a small watch icon, before it shows the number of changed files.

Comment: Created issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84921